# Pouchdb how can I putAttachment in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb, couchapp

I want to  add a few  attachments, and I can add one successfully,  but when in loop , it will just save one image: 5.png and get conflict error:

[image]

[image]

```
    function addNewDoc() {

        db.get('my0112doc', function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            // var blob = base64toBlob(imgSoucrce30m, 'image/png', 1024);
            var blob =imgSoucrce30m;
            var attachment = {
                content_type: 'image/png',
                data: blob
            }
            for (var i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
                var nameImg=i+'.png';
                db.putAttachment('my0112doc', nameImg, doc._rev, blob, 'text/plain', function(err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

====================new solution========================================

in my function , i have specified its revision _rev, but the conflict still occurs. I　cannot understand why.

CustomPouchError {status: 409, name: "conflict", message: "Document update conflict", error: true}

```
    function addNewDoc() {
        db.get('my0112doc', function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            // var blob = base64toBlob(imgSoucrce30m, 'image/png', 1024);
            var blob = imgSoucrce30m;
            addAttachment(5,doc._rev,blob);
        });
    }

    function addAttachment(counter,revId,blob) {
        var nameImg = counter + '.png';
        db.putAttachment('my0112doc', nameImg, revId, blob, 'text/plain', function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            if (counter >= 0) {
                addAttachment(counter - 1,revId,blob);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that `putAttachment` is asynchronous. So you need to wait for it to resolve before you can put again. I'm not sure if it returns a promise or not, but if not you could do something like this:

```
function addAttachment(counter) {
    var nameImg= counter + '.png';
    db.putAttachment('my0112doc', nameImg, doc._rev, blob, 'text/plain', function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        if (counter >= 0) {
            addAttachment(counter - 1);
        }
    });
}
addAttachment(5);
```

You could also do something with promises, but this just calls the next iteration when the previous put finishes. It stops once the counter is negative just like your `for loop`.

Comment: thanks winhowes, your answer is very helpful for me , i tried it, still i get the conflict error, I  have specified its revision _rev, i cannot  understand why the conflict occurs

Comment: I noticed you're passing in the same revID everytime, but wouldn't that change every time it's updated? Is the revID returned in the `res` object?

Comment: [This method will update an existing document to add the attachment, so it requires a rev if the document already exists. If the document doesn’t already exist, then this method will create an empty document containing the attachment.](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#save_attachment) .   I do it follow the API, my doc._rev is from my doc object, it's like this:  _rev: ""56-eb390d85ef90f92efdfc0cf458d2590b""

Comment: Right, but I think the _rev changes every time you update the doc, but you're passing the same _rev. I think you should be looking at the `res` to get the new _rev perhaps?

Comment: that's right,  every time , i want to save my attachment, i should have to get revid  first. Thanks man. :P

Comment: @AdvancingEnemy great would you mind marking this as the correct answer then? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try reading [We have a problem with promises](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) and in particular the section about "how do I use forEach() with promises?" You probably want to use `Promise.all()` since PouchDB's API returns promises.